# hey i have a problem in this clips code can any one please fix it?

Tags: clips, expert-system

this is a clips expert system code to make a diagnosis for a disease so i am trying to find out whats the problem in that code and i really dont know what to do
[CSTRCPSR1]
[CSTRCPSR2]

error

[image: 1]

```
defrule diagnosis
    (symptom ?s)
    (disease (symptoms ?s) (name ?d))
    =>
    (printout t "The patient may have " ?d "." crlf))

(defrule ask-symptoms
    (not (symptom ?))
    =>
    (bind ?symptom (read))
    (assert (symptom ?symptom)))

(defrule ask-symptoms
   (not (symptom ?))
   =>
   (printout t "What are the patient's symptoms?" crlf)
   (bind ?symptom (read))
   (assert (symptom ?symptom)))

(defrule ask-symptoms-2
   (symptom ?s)
   (not (symptom ?))
   =>
   (printout t "Any other symptom? " crlf)
   (bind ?symptom (read))
   (assert (symptom ?symptom)))

(defclass disease 
   (is-a USER)
   (role concrete)
   (multislot symptoms)
   (slot name))

(definstances diseases
   (disease (symptoms fever headache) (name "influenza"))
   (disease (symptoms fever sorethroat) (name "strep throat"))
   (disease (symptoms cough shortness-of-breath) (name "pneumonia"))
   (disease (symptoms stomachache nausea) (name "food poisoning")))
```

i tried everything to fix it but i really dont know where is the problem

Answer (score 0):

1. The diagnosis defrule is missing an opening parenthesis.
2. The diagnosis defrule references the disease defclass before the
   class is defined.
3. Classes automatically have a name slot defined.
4. You have two ask-symptoms rules.
5. The conditions of the ask-symptoms-2 rule will never be satisfied.
   Any fact matching the first pattern will cause the following pattern
   to fail.
6. If you want to read multiple symptoms, use the readline function
   along with the explode$ function.
7. In the diagnosis rule, you need to use the object keyword to match
   an instance of a defclass.
8. In the diagnosis rule, the disease pattern can only be matched by
   diseases with exactly one symptom.

For example:

```
         CLIPS (6.4 2/9/21)
CLIPS> 
(defclass disease 
   (is-a USER)
   (role concrete)
   (multislot symptoms)
   (slot text))
CLIPS> 
(defrule diagnosis
   (object (is-a disease) (name ?name) (text ?d))
   (exists
      (symptoms $? ?s $?)
      (object (is-a disease) (name ?name) (symptoms $? ?s $?)))
   =>
   (printout t "The patient may have " ?d "." crlf))
CLIPS> 
(defrule ask-symptoms
   =>
   (printout t "What are the patient's symptoms? ")
   (bind ?symptoms (readline))
   (assert (symptoms (explode$ ?symptoms))))
CLIPS> 
(definstances diseases
   (influenza of disease (symptoms fever headache) (text "influenza"))
   (strep-throat of disease (symptoms fever sorethroat) (text "strep throat"))
   (pneumonia  of disease (symptoms cough shortness-of-breath) (text "pneumonia"))
   (food-poisoning of disease (symptoms stomachache nausea) (text "food poisoning")))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
What are the patient's symptoms? cough nausea
The patient may have pneumonia.
The patient may have food poisoning.
CLIPS>
```